# Visual Studio: Callback function problem (__cdecl *)

Tags: c, visual-studio, casting, callback

I have a C application that works good on Ubuntu, but I have to port it to Visual Studio, and thats where problems start. I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and my problem is with callback functions that I use. 
Within the code, I have to register two callback functions (almost the same code, it's just that one is for sending data, other is for receiving it).

```
libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(recv_transfer_desc,         //transfer descriptor struct
        usb_dev_handle,             //usb device handle
        EP1_IN,                    //unsigned char
        in_buffer,                 //unsigned char*
        len,                        //tranfer length, int
        recv_transfer_finished_cb,  //callback func
        &my_recv_cb_data,           //void*, callback user data
        timeout);                 //unsigned int
```

This gives following error: `C2440 'function': cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(libusb_transfer *)' to 'libusb_transfer_cb_fn'`

I never use VS, so I really don't know how to fix this issue. To me it seams like something needs to be casted into something, but just can't figure it out.

This is the signature of callback function I'm trying to handle:
`static void recv_transfer_finished_cb(struct libusb_transfer *);`

Answer (score 1):

I've just figured it out, trough trial and error.

The problem was that default call in VS is `__cdecl`, and that can't be used for callback functions, which must be `__stdcall`.

To solve my problem, I needed to change signature of callback function from:
`static void send_transfer_finished_cb(struct libusb_transfer *);`
To:
`static void __stdcall send_transfer_finished_cb(struct libusb_transfer *);`